# Biztalk Editor v3 output specification without eol

Tags: biztalk, flat-file, eol

I have a problem with output spec, is possible to create the spec without any EOL character - flat file in one line?

I use BizTalk Editor v3.00... i think is a 2001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve problem, I changed in root of a document "Default Record Delimiter" to 'SPACE (0x20 )'

[image: Example of the change]

Comment: I hope your data doesn't have any spaces in it, otherwise it will think that is the end of your record.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean BizTalk 2010 (but it really doesn't matter :), the probable solution is to change the Child Order from PostFix (delimiter comes after) to Infix (delimiter comes between).

This would be on the Element that represents the 'row' in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define another record delimiter rather than a LF or CR LF.  For example this schema uses the pipe character to indicate the end of a record and commas to separate the fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.FlatFileSchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.FlatFileSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Root" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="infix" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="|" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3" name="Record1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_order="infix" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="," />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="2" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

File example

```
Field1A,Field2B|Field1B,Field2B|Field1C,Field2C
```